# Facepile displaying only my own profile picture

Tags: facebook, facepile

I have Facepile working on a website I've developed to show is is logging into our site using the app. It appears to be working correctly but only ever display a single profile picture (of the user viewing the site).

This happens despite the response test response displaying correctly as it day I 'and 2 other friends are using...'. I've looked through other facepile posts on here but not found any answers.

It's installed here if this helps: http://www.inhale.org.uk/

fb-login and facepile have been used separate for styling/layout reasons but the same issue occurs when using the showfaces attribute in fb-login on it's own.

Anyone else encountered similar? Please see the attached screenshot which presumable should show mine and 2 othe profile pictures. [facepile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaXlM.png)